# 1-D arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As far as I know 1-D arrays are those arrays which either have just 1 column and any number of rows or vice versa.

If I run this code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10).reshape(1,10)

b = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)

print(a.ndim, b.ndim)
```

It returns that both are 2-D arrays.
Why? I know the computer is working fine. But can you please tell me what is a 1-D array.

Comment: `x = np.arange(10)` is a 1-D array.  You can check that `x.ndim` is 1.

Comment: In highschool geometry, how wide is a line?  1 unit?

Comment: `ndim` is just the length of the `shape` tuple.

Answer (score 1):

A 1-D array is an array with just a single dimension. There are no columns or rows. It has a number of values in a line like say `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. The very concept of two separate dimensions row and columns do not apply to a 1-D array. Hence when you defined your first array with `.reshape(1,10)`, you gave it the dimensions- 1 and 10. Thus, you actually defined a 2-D array of dimension 1x10.

If you execute this code-

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10).reshape(1,10)

b = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)

print(a.ndim, b.ndim)
print(a)
print(b)
```

You will get this output-

```
2 2
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]
 [7]
 [8]
 [9]]
```

Which clearly shows that the array `a` has 2 dimensions- a row and a column, and hence is a 2-D array.

Answer (score 1):

This `.reshape(10,1)` reshapes the array to a 2-d array with 10 rows and 1 column. However, if using `.reshape(10)` instead you will get a 1-d array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `reshape`, you say `reshape(1,10)`. This means, reshape the array in a 2d matrix with 1 row and 10 columns. What you want is a 1d array so you need `reshape(10)`